# Using threading/multiprocessing in Python to download images concurrently

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have a list of search queries to build a dataset:

`classes = [...]`. There are 100 search queries in this list.

Basically, I divide the list into 4 chunks of 25 queries.

```
def divide_chunks(l, n):
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        yield classes[i:i + n]

classes = list(divide_chunks(classes, 25))
```

And below, I've created a function that downloads queries from each chunk iteratively:

```
def download_chunk(n):
    for label in classes[n]:
        try:
            downloader.download(label, limit=1000, output_dir='dataset', adult_filter_off=True, force_replace=False,verbose=True)
        except:
            pass
```

However, I want to run each 4 chunks concurrently. In other words, I want to run 4 separate iterative operations concurrently. I took both the `Threading` and `Multiprocessing` approaches but both of them don't work:

```
process_1 = Process(target=download_chunk(0))
process_1.start()
process_2 = Process(target=download_chunk(1))
process_2.start()
process_3 = Process(target=download_chunk(2))
process_3.start()
process_4 = Process(target=download_chunk(3))
process_4.start()

process_1.join()
process_2.join()
process_3.join()
process_4.join()

###########################################################

thread_1 = threading.Thread(target=download_chunk(0)).start()
thread_2 = threading.Thread(target=download_chunk(1)).start()
thread_3 = threading.Thread(target=download_chunk(2)).start()
thread_4 = threading.Thread(target=download_chunk(3)).start()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're running `download_chunk` outside of the thread/process. You need to provide the function and arguments separately in order to delay execution:

For example:

```
Process(target=download_chunk, args=(0,))
```

[Refer to the multiprocessing docs for more information about using the `multiprocessing.Process` class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process).

For this use-case, I would suggest using [`multiprocessing.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html):

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(4) as pool:
        pool.map(download_chunk, range(4))
```

It handles the work of creating, starting, and later joining the 4 processes. Each process calls `download_chunk` with each of the arguments provided in the iterable, which is `range(4)` in this case.

[More info about `multiprocessing.Pool` can be found in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map).

Comment: Is that the same rule for `threading.Thread()`?

Comment: Yes. They have similar APIs.

Comment: Could you elaborate the pool?